# Design where all associations tie to a team / community

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm interested in hearing how people design and set this up as I'm fairly inexperienced with this scenario.

Take for example a Rails application that allow people to create teams. Each team can have many projects, comments, members and other resources.

How do you structure this to avoid deep linking f.ex:

`nested_comment.root_comment.project.team`

I see this becoming problematic quite quickly, causing both performance issues and in general not very comfortable to work with.

Routes will also become complicated if the team ID is to present always, f.ex: `example.com/:team_name`

```
resources :teams do
  resources :projects do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

I know you can do shallow nesting, but the issue I see here is that you can use a slug but it will still require some deep linking. Furthermore even with shallow you won't avoid going more than 1 level deep, which the document recommends not doing.

```
Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.
```

What you could potentially do then is f.ex but it still needs to be two levels deep.

```
resources :teams do
  resources :projects, shallow: true do
   resources :comments
  end
  resources :comments, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end
```

By not having teams as the main resource, you'd open for security issues where people can edit other teams comments and projects unless you keep adding validations at controller and model level to ensure the user has access. Do people use trees or something?

Comment: Please add the associations from each of your models to your question. That would help me see exactly what it is you want to do.